# Positioning tikz nodes to the top

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I have four circles in a beamer frame,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[% common options for the circles:
ball/.style = {circle, draw, align=center, anchor=north, inner sep=0}]

\node<1>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=blue!20,draw=blue!20] (Post) at (6,2) {Post};
\node<2,3,4>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=purple!20,draw=purple!20] (A) at (6,2) {A};


\node<2>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=blue!20,draw=blue!20] (B) at (9,2) {B};
\node<1,3,4>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=purple!20,draw=purple!20] (B) at (9,2) {B};


\node<3>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=blue!20,draw=blue!20] (C) at (12,2) {C};
\node<1,2,4>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=purple!20,draw=purple!20] (C) at (12,2) {C};

\node<4>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=blue!20,draw=blue!20] (D) at (15,2) {D};
\node<1,2,3>[ball,text width=1.5cm,fill=purple!20,draw=purple!20] (D) at (15,2) {D};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is, when I change the y-coordinate of a node, it shifts up relative to the others. But as soon as I change it to the same value for all of them-- they all come back to the center.

How can I make them all shift to the top of the slide/frame?

Comment: Insert some vertical space below the picture or change the vertical alignment.

Comment: Use `\begin{frame}[t]`

Comment: More to the point, tikz only reserves space for the picture.  Where it actually appears depends on other factors.  There are many ways to control placement, but \raisebox is the most general.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `beamer` centers the frame content vertically.

By changing one y coordinate value, the picture size changes, and so does the vertical position then, because of the centering. By changing all y values in the same way, the picture size remains the same, so all is centered again.

You could leave at least one invisible node or coordinate unchanged, to see an effect of changing y values.

For example, add

```
\node at (9,0) {};
```

and then change the other nodes - all will move then.

For complete top alignment, simply use the `[t]` option to the frame:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible questions, here. One is beamer-specific, which you should use when you want the picture to be top-aligned. This is the optional `t` option to `\frame` and `\begin{frame}`. But this might not be enough if you want to create overlays in the drawing.

The secound option is to change the bounding box of your picture. The bounding box is by definition the rectangle that defines the dimensions of a picture as it is used by the software to fit it into the document. The behaviour of an image is defined by several boxes. There are other boxes like the clipping box (TikZ can use arbitray clipping paths) which defines the visible area of the picture.

You can compare it with a childres's drawing. If you say „You can draw in this rectanlge.” The child might not want or be able to keep the pencil in this area. Every stroke outside this area remains there. This is the behaviour of the bounding box. If you want to ensure that the drawing does not exceed a certain area you have to use a different sheet of paper, cut out the finished image and glue it into your document. This is what clipping does.

You can define the bounding box of an image using `\useasboundingbox` somewhere in your picture. For example:

```
\useasboundingbox (0,0) -- (1,1);
```

This will tell TeX that the image has a size of $1\times 1$ units. And it will fit exactly the area of the rectangle from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)` into this box. Everything else will not be considered by TeX. This can be used to create funny effects.

The TikZ manual (`texdoc pgfmanual`) has further examples.

On the other hand you can acess the current bounding box of your TikZ picture by accessing the node `current bounding box` so you can easily strike out your picture with:

```
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south east) -- (current bounding box.north west);
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.noth east);
```